# How to add helptext when mouse hovers on text?

Tags: html, django

HTML:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; background-color: #2370b4">
    <li style="float:left; display:block; text-align:center; padding:14px 16px; text-decoration:none"><a class="active" href="/home/" style="color:white">Home</a></li>
    <li style="float:left; display:block; text-align:center; padding:14px 16px; text-decoration:none"><a href="/search/" style="color:white">Search</a></li>
    <li style="float:left; display:block; text-align:center; padding:14px 16px; text-decoration:none"><a href="/upload/" style="color:white">Library</a></li>
    <li style="float:left; display:block; text-align:center; padding:14px 16px; text-decoration:none"><a href="/adddata/" style="color:white">Add Data</a></li>
    <li style="float:left; display:block; text-align:center; padding:14px 16px; text-decoration:none"><a href="#about" style="color:white">About</a></li>
    <li style="float:right; display:block; text-align:center; padding:14px 16px; text-decoration:none"><i>{{ username }}</i></li>
    <li style="float:right; display:block; text-align:center; padding:14px 16px; text-decoration:none"><a href="/logout/" style="color:white">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here I have my tabs and I want to display some help text when the cursor is hovering over, e.g. when cursor hovers over "Search", it should display "Search questions and responses".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no requirements on the design, I'd go with `title` attributes:

```
<li style="float:left; display:block; text-align:center; padding:14px 16px; text-decoration:none">
    <a href="/search/" style="color:white" title="Search questions and responses">
        Search
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Title in HTML tags to display help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add title attribute as follows to the tag,
< a href="#" title="help text" > Help </a>